# Retrieving files from Storage Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on an upload and download functionality in my Laravel 5.4 application. I am having problems with getting the files from storage.

The upload functionality:

```
Storage::put('app/public/uploads/' . $filename, $file);
```

I have created a link between the public folder and storage `php artisan storage:link`.

The download functionality:

```
Storage::get('app/public/uploads/' . $file->filename)
```

The folder in which the document is: `/Users/anna/Sites/project/version2/storage/app/public/uploads/dkfjlasd.pdf`

The error which I am getting now is: **FileNotFoundException**
app/public/uploads/dkfjlasd.pdf.

Could someone please help me explain what the problem is? Because I am putting the file in the same place as where I am retrieving it from.

Comment: did you actually looked in the folder to see if the file was written or does it exist with the same name?

Comment: Yes it is! The path which I have in my question is copied from the file.

Comment: better to use `asset()` which starts from `app/public` directory.

Comment: your snippet does not set the public disk.  Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');

Comment: Use asset function like asset('storage/app/public/'.$filename );

Comment: @AnnaJeanine  NP!